# Pattern matching in Java with punctuations

Tags: java, regex

I want to provide support to match both punctuations and regex characters in Java. The support for punctuations is working fine, but it is failing for even simple regexes.

Here's my pattern:

```
(\s\p{Punct}|^\p{Punct}|\s|^)ros?(\s|\p{Punct}|$)
```

And content I'm trying to match: `rose`

find() method is returning false for this pattern. I initially thought that root cause was the `{Punct}` part of the pattern so I tried changing my regex to  `(\s\p{Punct}|^\p{Punct}|\s|^)ro?e(\s|\p{Punct}|$)` in my unit test,  but even that is failing

Comment: I don't see anything that matches the `e`.  I think you may be confused about `?`.  This means to match 0 or 1 occurrences of the previous character, so `ros?` matches `ro` or `ros`.  It does not match "any character" the way it would in a Linux file name wildcard.  If that's what you want, use a period (`.`) which matches any character.

Comment: I think you are misapplying the `^` special character.  Are you trying to use it to match the beginning of the input string, to negate, or to do both?

Comment: If you want to find `ros` in `rose`, this works: http://ideone.com/pljbKU (add an empty alternation after the `$`)

Comment: please provide examples of text you want to match, and examples of text you don't want to match

Comment: @ajb Thanks, I confused Linux regexes with Java's. Replacing ? with . solved my problem.

Comment: FYI, I don't think the wildcard syntax in Linux is called "regex" or "regular expression".  It probably has some other name, but I can't think what it is.  But it might help avoid confusion if you avoid calling them regexes.

Comment: The `?` and `*` in Unix shell is not a "Linux regex", it is a "shell globbing" wildcard. Regular expressions in Linux (grep, sed, awk) all use `.` for a single replace char as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not match because the `'e'` in "rose" is not a punctuation or whitespace character.

Besides the `ros?` in your pattern makes only the `s` only optional.

Note: The `?` and `*` in Unix shell is not a "Linux regex", it is a "shell globbing" wildcard. Regular expressions in Linux (grep, sed, awk) all use `.` for a single replace char.